# Definition of torsion free sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory

I know a definition of torsion free sheaf  $\mathcal{F}$ on an integral scheme X, That is: $\mathcal F$ is  an quasi-coherent sheaf such that it hasn't have not-null torsion sections, which is equivalent to $\forall U$  affine open subset $\mathcal F(U)$ is a torsion free $\mathcal O(U)$-module [Torsion free modules](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AVQ).

Does a generalization for torsion free sheafs on complex manifolds exists? Which is it?

Comment: @JCAA But in that question, $X$ is a integral noetherian scheme too, I want to know if there exists a more general definition for torsion free sheaf on complex manifolds or ringed spaces. I don't know if any complex manifold is an integral notherian scheme, if it is, yes, that will answer my question, but I think that it is not, based on what is pointed on the following link [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577338/is-every-complex-smooth-manifold-a-scheme)

Comment: OK. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the issue you're worried about.  Can't you just define a torsion-free sheaf on a complex manifold (possibly not algebraic) to be a quasi-coherent sheaf with no torsion subsheaves?

Comment: I agree with Benighted. You can easily make up a definition of torsion-free modules for arbitrary locally ringed spaces by adapting one of the four definitions given in the stacks project. More interesting questions are: (a) are those equivalent for general locally ringed spaces?; (b) is at least one of them a "good" definition in the case of complex manifolds? Of course, an answer to (b) depends on what you want to be able to do.

Comment: Thank you @Benighted and Nils Matthes.  Well, I don't feel sufficently confiant to define torsion-free sheaf this way or any way, I just will to know if such definition actually exists. **Benighted** your definition is more general, so why in the definition of _stack project_ it's necessary the scheme $X$  to be integral?

Comment: @Nils Matthes I understand your point, I just need to know if that ''good'' definition exists and also a reference for such definition.

Comment: @Protágoras To answer your question in the comments, you should think about the case of modules.  I believe people typically only define torsion-free modules over rings which are integral domains.  After all, a ring will not be a torsion-free module over itself if there are zero divisors!  So if your scheme is not integral, any definition using, say, ordinary modules over an open set will not make sense.  I believe the definition I gave is the most general--there are more standard ones, but which may only apply when the scheme is integral.

Comment: @Benighted: Maybe I missed your point but you can certainly define torsion-free modules over a general ring $R$ which don't suffer from that pathology. Simply define an $R$-module $M$ to be *torsion-free*, if $rm=0$, with $r \in R$ not a zero-divisor, implies that $m=0$. However, I should warn you that I haven't thought at all about that notion and didn't find it in the usual trustworthy references (EGA, Stacks Project) after a superficial search, so there could be something (even pretty obvious) wrong with that.

Comment: @NilsMatthes I see, it seems you're right.  Looking at a few sources, people give your definition in the case with zero divisors, but mention that many authors only define torsion-free modules over integral domains.  Perhaps for convenience.  See the paragraph after Remark 2.3 of (https://www.math.utah.edu/~schwede/MichiganClasses/math632/GeneralizedDivisors.pdf).